# Override SharePoint:SaveButton click event Share Point

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have created a custom Share Point 2010 webpart, in which i take input from user, basically it is a new form. I have a predefined list for data storage, I used

```
<SharePoint:FormField ID="id" runat="server" ControlMode="New" FieldName="name" > 
</SharePoint:FormField>
```

and used

```
 <SharePoint:SaveButton ID="SP_save" runat="server" ControlMode="New" >   
 </SharePoint:SaveButton>
```

to save the form fields.
All it is working fine, it takes the valid data in input and shows proper validation messages.
but there is a problem i am facing, since i have no access to SharePoint:SaveButton click event and can't override it to my custom event

for example, I have a requirement to save the data in list and then perform some another task based on input, so how i do that

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom `SaveButton` and override the `SaveItem` method.

**Code:**

```
namespace CustomOverrideControls
{
    public class CustomSaveButton : SaveButton
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        protected override bool SaveItem()
        {
            // Do the custom code here
            return base.SaveItem();
        }
    }
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<CustomOverrideControls:CustomSaveButton ID="SP_save" runat="server"
    ControlMode="New">
</CustomOverrideControls:CustomSaveButton>
```

I took the above example from the article [How to override or customize the SharePoint SaveButton?](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/murugangs/archive/2007/05/28/How-to-override-or-customize-the-Sharepoint-SaveButton_3F00_.aspx) that also contains a complete project for download.

Comment: actually i want to redirect user to some my defined page, so in saveitem(), i set the RedirectUrl, but it is not redirecting to my defined page?

Comment: @Saboor Awan: I would simply call the `Response.Redirect` method after `base.SaveItem`, but you can also try to modify the new item button URL by adding `?source=http://[site]/[library]/CustomRedirectPage.aspx` (http://www.graphicalwonder.com/?p=666).